# How to appendChild in the Wix Corvid/Code IDE

Tags: velo

I've searched thru Corvid docs and Stack, not finding anything.

Is there a way to `appendChild()` in Wix Corvid(Code)?

EDIT: Wix does not allow DOM access directly. I assumed that people answering this would know i was looking for an alternative to appencChild and knew this method could not be used as is in Wix.

so to clarify: is there a way to add a child to a parent element using Wix's APIs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Corvid, you cannot use any function which accesses the DOM.

Coming from one of the developers of Corvid:

*Accessing document elements such as div, span, button, etc is off-limits. The way to access elements on the page is only through $w. One small exception is the $w.HtmlComponent (which is based on an iFrame). This element was designed to contain vanilla HTML and it works just fine. You just can't try to trick it by using parent, window, top, etc.*

*Javascript files can be added to your site's Public folder, but the same limitations apply - no access to the DOM.*

Read more here: https://www.wix.com/corvid/forum/main/comment/5afd2dd4f89ea1001300319e

Comment: I do understand you cant access the DOM in wix, but they have APIs that let you select the elements and add content, change html, etc. i guess i am looking for an alternative to appendChild. +1 on the answer, and thanks. ill edit my question.

Answer (score 4):

It depends what you are trying to achieve,
the only thing off the top of my head is adding more items to a repeater

which you can do by first getting the initial data from the repeater, adding another item to array and reassign the data property of the repeater

```
const initialData = $w('#repeater').data
const newItem = {
   _id: 'newItem1', // Must have an _id property
   content: 'some content'
}
const newData = [...initialData, newItem]
$w('#repeater').data = newData
```

https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/$w.Repeater.html#data